# Accept incoming HTTP requests in a Cordova/PhoneGap application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, httprequest

I'm in the process of building a Cordova application that needs to talk to a hardware device I'm building. The device can transmit HTTP requests, but can't accept requests. Both the app and device are the only devices on the local network with no internet access.

Are there anyways for the Cordova application to receive incoming HTTP requests from the hardware device?

If it helps the app needs to support Android (with iOS coming out in the near future).

Comment: Have u tried node.js?... Maybe the runtime won't allow you to liaten to a port but may be worth a try

Comment: Even though Cordova use Node for its deployment, I don't believe there is anyway for me to embed a node server into a Cordova app.

Comment: Ok. Bad answer. You can open a port and listen from java and publish events to your webview. Maybe one small thing already done can be embedded https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a plugin that does what I need - https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-discovery

Props to eduyayo for putting me on the right track

Comment: Did you manage to use cordova-plugin-discovery? I'm at a loss trying to understand how it works. Perhaps you could help out with a quick example?
Is it used to connect to a broadcasting server or iterate through all the devices on the network? Thanks!